# Sort and move folders and contents by a criteria

Tags: windows-7, sorting

Using Windows 7
I have a folder with several thousand sub folders.  Each sub folder may have subfolders of files.  A Music Library Might be a good example.

I need to sort the top most subfolder and its contents to another location and group by first letter.

Example.
source
d:\Music\Abba
d:\Music\All-in-one
d:\Music\A Artist
d:\Music\B.B. King
d:\Music\Barney

Destination
m:\sorted_Music\A\Abba
m:\sorted_Music\A\All-in-one
m:\sorted_Music\A\A Artist
m:\sorted_Music\B\B.B. King
m:\sorted_Music\B\Barney

I have tried Robocopy, and move commands.

There used to be a scripting program YEARS>>>>ago called LaunchPad.  I recall being able to do it from there.  But I think that app dies With Win 95..

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many levels down do you need to go? In other words, is it always going to be e.g., S:\Top-Dir\Sort-These to D:\Top-Dir\Sort-Letter\Sort-These, or will the depth of Sort-These vary from item to item?

Comment: There could be any number of sub folders.

Comment: In other words, it varies from item to item, as opposed to all items being at the same depth?